# AWS DMS ongoing replication task getting failed as source SQL tables are compressed

Tags: sql-server, replication, dms

I am trying to run an AWS DMS ongoing replication task with Microsoft SQL server as source and S3 bucket as target. After some time the task is failing with the following error:

Last Error Task 'JNDGFTDYD' was suspended due to 6 successive unexpected failures Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

and in logs I can see:

[SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]I:  Table table_name is compressed.  (sqlserver_log_utils.c:1101)

for multiple tables.

Can someone help me to fix this? Is there any setttings on the DMS side I need to enable?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your MS SQL Server and what type of compression is used?

I would recommend you to go through following link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.Compression

This AWS guide will tell you if DMS can support compression for your MS SQL server version.
thanks,
Naveed.